# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gettierone()

Tags: php

Hello guys i hope you be happy and healthy.

i have created a function in a separet page and included in my page for calling but its saying that: Fatal error: Call to undefined function gettierone()

here is my code when i call the function any one please:

```
  <option style="width:150px;" value=" " selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Your Province</option>

  <?php 
  getTierOne(); 
  ?>

</select><br />
```

Comment: your function is not exist !

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that your function was not defined earlier or you have a typo in the function name. You may also need to include remaining php file that contains this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the function within your page, you have to include the page where the function `gettierone()` is defined:

```
<?php
include("dir/to/the/other/page.php");
?>
```

Comment: i have includeed at the top of the page and call it in middle of page but not working. its located in a folder name ProDisPds/func.php  and i have call it like. <?php getTierOne(); ?>

Comment: No, you only have to include the file: `<?php include("ProDisPds/func.php"); ?>`

Comment: i did include <?php include("ProDisPds/func.php"); ?> but still receiving : Fatal error: Call to undefined function gettierone() in /home/a8439146/public_html/Admin Panel/Property_Insert_Page.php on line 186

Comment: Check the names and check also you include before calling the function.